# Why do mailto links in Notes fail with double-quotes fail in Inbox?

Tags: lotus-notes, mailto

We're sending email from Newsgator to Notes mail as part of our social implementation. It includes three links that are mailto's. The hotspot formula looks like this:

```
"mailto:"Like Event" <SocialActivityStream@DAIPortal.daiglobal.net>?subject=Like this activity event. This email references activity event:NGMetaEvent_0D8111ED124B8FE8693DD6C82BD0FA28_634984171780151056.&body=Send this email to like the activity event."
```

I would expect this to always fail, because of the multiple double-quotes.

Interestingly, it does not always fail. If you put it in your trash folder, it works. If you forward the document, the recipient will be able to click the links. If you simply edit and save the received message, the links work. The hotspot formula looks exactly the same in any of those circumstances.

So, why does it fail when I open the document from my Inbox?

Comment: What happens if you omit the quotes around "Like Event"?  Since you are using the < and > characters, the quotes are not required by standards.  (Not sure about whether they're required/expected by any particular code, mind you, but they are not required by the RFC-5322 standard for mail address format.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz It's hard to say, because as soon as you save it in Notes, it doesn't matter that it has double quotes twice. I'm wondering what it is about displaying it via the Inbox as opposed to Trash makes it incapable of handling the inner double quotes. I can understand forwarding or editing/saving "fixing" it, but why would it care whether it had been opened from Inbox or Trash matter (yes, moving the document back-and-forth does change whether it works, multiple instances of back-and-forth with the same document).

Comment: Interesting.  I don't have a clue why it would make a difference that it is in Trash.  There may be some filtering going on in the code to make sure that links are "safe", but I would expect that filtering to still be in place no matter what folder you're in.